# Access 2D array with 1D iteration

Tags: c++, c++11

If I define an array as follows:

```
int rows = 10;
int cols = 10;

double **mat;
mat = new double*[rows];
mat[0] = new double[rows*cols];

for(int r=1; r<10; r++)
    mat[r] = &(mat[0][r*cols]);
```

How do I iterate over this array via 1-dimension?
E.g. I'd like to do the following:

```
mat[10] = 1;
```

to achieve the same thing as

```
mat[1][0] = 1;
```

Is there a way to dereference the double** array to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your definition of `mat`, you can do this:

```
double* v = mat[0]; 'use v a uni-dimensional vector
for(int i =0; i< rows* cols; i++) v[i] = 1;
```

Alternatively,if what you wanted was to define `mat` itself as a uni-dimensional vector and use it as bi-dimensional in a tricky way:

```
double mat[rows * cols];
#define MAT(i, j) mat[i*cols + j]

MAT(1, 0) = 1;
<=>
mat[10] = 1
```

now you have the options to span the matrix in one-dimension using `mat` or bi-dimension using the `MAT` macro

Comment: @RobinHartland possible and interesting, but I have seen some (mainly C) compilers that wont accept this, so i prefer to avoid it in general. Moreover, that will NOT permit `mat[1][0]` nor `MAT[1][0]`, but `mat(1, 0)` or  `MAT(1, 0)`.

Comment: true, and yours is less confusing :P

Answer (score 1):

```
mat[row * cols + column]
```

where `row` is the row you want to access and `column` is the column you want to access.

Of course an iteration over the array would just involve some kind of loop (best suited would be `for`) and just applying the pattern every time.

Comment: Oops. You need to access `mat[0][row * cols + column]`.

Comment: @Dúthomhas What do you mean?

Comment: OP's array is not flat. `mat` is an array of _pointers_. `mat[0]` is an array of `rows*cols` values.

Comment: Dúthomhas is correct, this is pre-existing code which is why I can't redefine the array to my liking.... and I'm a tard for not seeing that. Thanks dude